# How do I make Vulcanize ignore a js file in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I have several sites in Polymer where I am relying on external js files for configuration. These files need to be easy to modify later and therefore I do not want to have them vulcanized into the main html file. How do I get Vulcanize to ignore a specific file. I am just using vulcanize --inline-scripts --inline-css
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--exclude <path>` option. From the [docs](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize#options):

> exclude a subpath from root. Use multiple times to exclude multiple paths. Tags (imports/scripts/etc) that reference an excluded path are left in-place, meaning the resources are not inlined. ex: `--exclude=elements/x-foo.html --exclude=elements/x-bar.html`

Comment: Sorry about the delay in answering ... thanks a lot for the reply :-)